# When the accuracy curve is U-shaped

Tags: model-evaluation, recommender-system

I am currently working on MLP-based recommendation system.

During training, the model updates based on BCE loss function with train set, then shows the hit rate (rate of how ground truth item is in top k recommendation from the model for a given user) on val set. What I found intriguing is that the hit rate curve shows the U-shape, which means the model tends to show less accuracy then suddenly increases its performance. Moreover, this tendency seems to keep showing with different hyperparameters - learning rate, number of layers or features, dropouts etc.

(x-axis is the epoch)

[image: hitrate curve through epoch]

Although I think this is still kind of overfitting, especially considering this decreasing nDCG (logarithmic score of how highly the ground truth item is recommended from the model for a given user) curve.

[image]

I am curious what can possibly cause this sudden drift of performance. If you know anything about this U-shaped tendency in accuracy curve, I would love to know about it!

Comment: What's on the x-axis?

Comment: @Tim sorry, I thought I add that part. the x-axis is the epoch!